# Restore label to variables when switching back to a view

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and have been building a timer app. The main (first) view controller is a stopwatch.

Recently, I added another view controller to view splits from the stopwatch. My problem occurs when the timer has been or is running and the user switches to the second view controller and then returns to the main view controller.

Instead of displaying the correct stopwatch time (for example: 12:34.56), the label is reset to the default text I have for the stopwatch (00:00.00). If I resume the stopwatch, it now restarts from where it left off (this is how I intend for it to function since the user has not manually reset the watch).

How can I display the current time immediately when switching back to the stopwatch view controller?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much! I already was just calling on another function (saved elsewhere) that stored and updated the time, so I just called on it in the view did load and it worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem! I've posted an answer to the question so it will be easier for others to find. Once you're satisfied with one of the answers, you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/238826)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current time in a global variable before going to the split view. Then, on the `viewDidAppear` method of the original view, set the label to the correct string based on what is stored in the variable

For an over-simplified example

```
//set to "00:00.00" by default
var currentTime: String = "00:00.00"

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    myLabel.text = currentTime
}

func goToSplitView(){
    currentTime = myLabel.text
}
```